# Array of combinations to pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

For my machine learning project I have got a pandas dataframe which looks like this and contains all products a customer has bought:

| product_ids |
| --- |
| 12, 223 |
| 54, 554, 12 |
| 12, 1112,11, 2353,445 |
| 54,12 |

But the data should be a data frame containing pairs of products, so I need all possible combinations of the products bought. For example:

| product_one | product_two |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 223 |
| 54 | 554 |
| 54 | 12 |
| 12 | 554 |
| ... | ... |

I have used pythons itertools.combinations to get all unique combinations for every row.
The output looks like this:

```
[('12', '223')]

[('54', '554'), ('54', '12'), ('554', '12')]

[('2', '1112'), ('2', '11'), ('2', '2353'), ('2', '44'), ('1112', '11'), ('1112', '2353'), ('1112', '44'), ('11', '2353'), ('11', '44'), ('2353', '44')]
```

How can I split these lists into a data frame like shown in example two?
Basically, I just want the tuples inside the list like

```
[('12', '223')]
```

to be a row in a data frame.

Any help or any tip is appreciated!

Comment: how exactly the input from the itertools.combinations looks like? is it list of lists contains pair?

Answer (score 0):

Find all numbers and get all combinations for each row then expand vertically (explode) and horizontally (apply) the result of combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations

>>> df['product_ids'].str.findall('\d+') \
                     .apply(lambda l: list(combinations(l, r=2))) \
                     .explode() \
                     .apply(pd.Series)

      0     1
0    12   223
1    54   554
1    54    12
1   554    12
2    12  1112
2    12    11
2    12  2353
2    12   445
2  1112    11
2  1112  2353
2  1112   445
2    11  2353
2    11   445
2  2353   445
3    54    12
```